# How to draw trend line for an uptrend with noticeable discrete points

Tags: technical-analysis, trend-trading

as you see in the following picture, the A waves are ascending(rally) and the B waves are also ascending(again rally)
so there is no swing point, in the other words there is no high and low point and only there is discrete points which connect the successive ascending waves

[image: the mentioned odd price diagram!!]

since obviously the overall trend is not along with the A rallies or the B rallies, it seems that the drawn dashed line to be valid and is a good representative for overall price trend, although the line has been drawn without any swing point

am I wrong?
are we not allowed to do this?
actually is this trend-line valid? or even is this line a trend-line?
please tell me what do you prefer in such cases?

Comment: A trendline is the line or curve drawn that best fits the data.  Your graph depicts that.  I'm not sure what all of your other details have to do with this.

Comment: @BobBaerker I'm agree with you؛ but in some resourses I have found those details that the trend-line must connect at least 3 swing points to consider it as a reliable trend-line and thus we can trust on it and setup our strategies based on it؛ those resourses emphasized swing point is the connection of ascending and discending waves not 2 similar waves(which has been called as wrong swing point by my resourse and  teacher) otherwise our trend-line(drawn by wrong swing points) is garbage; I did need someone pro who confirms that these details are redundant , thanks

Comment: Drawing trendlines is an arbitrary process subject to the user's interpretation.  For that reason it is by no means precise unless formula based (Parabolic SAR, Andrew's Pitchfork, etc.).  Here's a prediction for you:  Some day you're going to realize that none of this as well as most of the technical analysis  mumbo jumbo is unreliable and perhaps the you'll evolve past it.  For now, put in your time and follow your resource and your teacher until you can evaluate things for yourself.